# Azure policy exemption using New-AzPolicyExemption not working

Tags: powershell, azure-policy

Trying to create policy exemptions using code as opposed to manually creating them.
According to the MS link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azpolicyexemption?view=azps-11.1.0) it ought to be straight forward but this has not been my experience.

I have a policy initiative which consists of multiple sub policies. The first issue is that  I cannot seem to get the correct `-Name` passed to `New-AzPolicyExemption`

This doesn't work.

```
$mgmtGroup = 'xxx'
$policySetName = 'xxx'
Get-AzPolicySetDefinition -ManagementGroupName $mgmtGroup -Custom | Where {$_.Properties.DisplayName -eq $policySetName } | Select-Object Name
```

I can see the display name on the portal, but I do not know what the internal name is. I believe this is stored within the properties object when you run `Get-AzPolicySetDefinition` how can one display all the values within the property object ?

Going back to the main question

Running the below fails because it cannot find the `Name` parameter.

```
ResourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name 'ResourceGroup11'
$intiative = Get-AzPolicySetDefinition | Where-Object { $_.Properties.DisplayName -eq 'Public' }
New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name 'denyPolicies' -PolicySetDefinition $intiative -Scope $ResourceGroup.ResourceId
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can see the display name on the portal, but I do not know what the internal name is. I believe this is stored within the properties object when you run `Get-AzPolicySetDefinition` how can one display
> all the values within the property object ?

Here is the `PowerShell` script that retrieves custom policy set definitions with the `display name`.

```
$policySetName = "srbose AKS node RG tagging"
$ResourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name 'RG-Name'
$intiative = Get-AzPolicySetDefinition  -Custom | Select-Object -ExpandProperty properties | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq $policySetName } | Select-Object -Property DisplayName
```

**Output:**

[image]

Here is a `PowerShell` script to create policy exemptions for an existing `Policy Initiative`.

```
 $policySetName = "Billing Tags Policy Initiative"
  $ResourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name 'RG-Name'
  $intiative = Get-AzPolicySetDefinition -Custom | Where-Object {$_.Properties.DisplayName -eq $policySetName }
 $Assignment = New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name 'demopolicytest3' -PolicySetDefinition $intiative -Scope $ResourceGroup.ResourceId
    
 New-AzPolicyExemption -Name 'sampleexception' -PolicyAssignment $Assignment -Scope $ResourceGroup.ResourceId  -ExemptionCategory Waiver
```

**Output:**

[image]